# Name and Author of book where man creates computer called Satan

Tags: story-identification, books, computers

I read (but never finished) a book in the 1980's where a man has dreams to build a computer. He draws all the schematics and builds it.
On powering it up he asks the question - Who Are You? (Or something like that.)
The computer replies that it is Satan, the Devil, Lucifer, or some-such.
The book goes on but I never finished it.
Does anyone happen to know the name and author of this book?

If it helps, I loaned the book from Uxbridge town library, Middlesex, UK in autumn 1988.

Comment: When you say the man "has dreams" of building a computer, are you speaking figuratively, or do you mean the plans for the computer literally come to him in his sleep? Was the computer handheld or desktop size, or did it fill a big room? Did the man build the computer at home, or at work in some industrial or government laboratory?

Comment: The man dreamt the schematics while he was asleep. I think it was a desktop sized computer. And I think he built it at home, possibly having obtained the hardware and components from his work. I say "I think" because I can't be definite.

Comment: I too am hunting for this author. The chunky paperback I had, late '80s, had a bright red cover with 'Satan' in large letters. I vaguely recall the story had some sex scene in it involving the actual computer.

Comment: Are you certain it's not FuzzyBoots' suggestion? The [Wikipedia description](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satan,_His_Psychotherapy_and_Cure_by_the_Unfortunate_Dr._Kassler,_J.S.P.S.) of the book's Dr. Leo Szlyck  character seems to match.

Comment: Yes, absolutely positive it is not that book, confirmed when I read the Wikipedia description. Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: I don't think it can be the one due to the 1998 date, but take a look at this Google Books search result: https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Scribners_Best_of_the_Fiction_Workshops/gPU9wh-xD08C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=computer+%22who+are+you%22+satan&pg=PA245&printsec=frontcover

Answer (score 3):

Could it be *[Satan: His Psychotherapy and Cure by the Unfortunate Dr. Kassler, J.S.P.S.](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/201669.Satan_His_Psychotherapy_and_Cure_by_the_Unfortunate_Dr_Kassler_J_S_P_S_)* by Jeremy Leven?

> Alas, poor Satan. He's not happy. No one seems to like or understand him; people have got him all wrong. And his relationship with God is a hostile one. Unloved and misunderstood, he's come back to Earth in search of a psychotherapist; he's prepared- if cured- to deliver the all-important Great Answer.In Jeremy Leven's wildly original comic novel, we follow the Prince of Darkness through his seven amazing therapy sessions. And we watch him grow increasingly well adjusted while his therapist, the unfortunate Dr. Kassler, descends deeper and deeper into hell.

It was published in 1982 and [some of the reviews](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/22076865?book_show_action=true) mention that Satan manifests on a computer.

> No one has ever done a subtler or a more devastating send up of the psychiatric/psychology industry, nor have many been able to insinuate sly philosophical digressions into a frothing satiric text with such grace and pacing. This satan, faceless, locking himself inside a computer in a public gallery, has the charm to coax a snake out of new skin. The complications are wonderfully wild and orchestrated, and Kassler's travails as a single dad trying to rekindle a relationship with his children are heart breaking as they are potently hilarious.

If so, I found it by searching for *book man dreams of computer named satan*

Comment: Thank you.
Yes, I have come across that book. And bought it although I cannot lay my hands on it at home.
But it is not the one I am searching for. I am beginning to wonder if I didn't dream the book myself.

Comment: @JordanWalters Whatever you do, don't try to re-create what you're dreaming about!